# Loaders don't apply to files resolved through the alias

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I assume webpack loaders don't apply to files resolved through the alias.
Have someone faced with such an issue?  Or could someone refute this assumption?

Full context:

I develop my own npm package `my-package`. Also, I have a test-project using this `my-package`. For improving development experience I want to create a separate webpack config which would replace `my-package` from `node_modules` with local package src files.

It works but I got next error in one of `my-package` files:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (35:20):

  33 | 
  34 | class AddressForm extends PureComponent {
> 35 |   static propTypes = {
     |                    ^
  36 |     // eslint-disable-next-line react/require-default-props
  37 |     onSubmit: (props, propName) => {
  38 |       if (

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

I have `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in my `.babelrc` file and I use class properties in test-project files.

Here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: {
    'integration-test-page': './src/integration-test-page/index.jsx',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/integration-test-page/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'my-package': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        '../my-package/src/index.js'
      ),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it. I have to add `babelrcRoots: ['.', '../'],` to my `babel.config.js`

Here are details about babel config for monorepos https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos